# Why am I getting TypeError jsdom.createVirtualConsole() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I'm doing some prework for a bootcamp. I have an environment set up using WSL, ubuntu, node.js, python and ruby. when I run `npm list jsdom` I get jsdom 20.0.3.

I'm trying to run a test in VS using learn.co. When I run learn test in VS I get this error in my terminal:

```
java-script-intro-to-functions-lab@0.1.0 test
mocha --timeout 5000 -R mocha-multi --reporter-options spec=-,json=.results.json

0 passing (106ms)   1 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     TypeError: jsdom.createVirtualConsole is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/root.js:18:27)
      at process.processImmediate 
(node:internal/timers:471:21)
```

This is from my root.js file.

```js
lobal.expect = require("expect");

const babel = require("babel-core");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const path = require("path");

before(function (done) {
  const babelResult = babel.transformFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "index.js"),
    {
      presets: ["es2015"],
    }
  );

  const html = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "index.html");
  jsdom.env(
    html,
    [],
    {
      src: babelResult.code,
      virtualConsole: jsdom.createVirtualConsole().sendTo(console),
    },
    (err, window) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
        global[key] = window[key];
      });

      return done();
    }
  );
});
```

These are the dependencies from the package.json

```
"devDependencies": {  
  "babel-core": "^6.11.4",  
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",  
  "expect": "^1.20.2",  
  "jsdom": "^20.0.3",  
  "mocha": "^10.2.0",  
  "mocha-jsdom": "~1.1.0",  
  "mocha-multi": "^1.1.3"   
}
```

I've also tried `virtualConsole: new jsdom.VirtualConsole().sendTo(console)` but this gives a `TypeError: jsdom.env is not a function`.

This is the output from npm audit -fix -force:

> npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled. npm WARN
> audit Updating jsdom to 20.0.3, which is a SemVer major change. npm
> WARN audit Updating mocha to 10.2.0, which is a SemVer major change.

I noticed it changed mocha and jsdom. I looked at the original file and the versions for the dependencies were different in package.json. Below are the dependencies before the npm audit.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "jsdom": "^9.2.1",
    "mocha": "5.2.0",
    "mocha-jsdom": "~1.1.0",
    "mocha-multi": "^1.1.3"
  }
```

Anyway I was able to reinstall my lab environment from github and ignore the warnings about dependency issues and now things are working.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo that did change the error, but I thought it was best I try to explain in more detail what I was trying to do.  I'm really hoping someone could just give me an idea of what could be the problem, like a dependency issue or something.  BTW, I honestly was not trying to circumvent the filter, there should have been a difference between the two code pieces, one should have read jsdom.VirtualConsole() and the other jsdom.createVirturalConsole(). Anyway please give me a little grace as I'm new to this.

Comment: Sorry, my edit was bad. I didn't pay attention. Thanks for the update. I still see no documentation for `sentTo`. Where are you seeing that? I believe it should be `sendTo`.

Comment: I'm sorry you are correct its sendTo.  I've been looking at the stuff for so long everything is starting to blur.  I changed it to sendto and still get the same error.

Comment: I believe this has to do with dependencies issues. I recently ran npm audit because I had a bunch of dependency errors and the output suggested I do that.  I think that changed some of the dependencies which is causing this error.

Comment: Yep. Looks like the syntax now is: `const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();` according to the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). Other things may have changed as well, so you might need to downgrade, then take time to figure out all of the differences to get a clean upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You that error because there is no such function. It existed years ago in jsdom version 9.... not 20, so whole example where you copy pated your solution is out of date and you might get more errors. To create virtual console you need:

```
const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
```

or in your example:

```
virtualConsole: new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
```